# Can I accept mails for an exchange account only during a specified time frame?

Tags: exchange-2007

My bosses want an auction email account in Exchange 2007. There would be an address (mailbox), that can get email only during a certain time frame. Before and after that it rejects the email?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can disable the mailbox in the scheduled time, using simple scheduler provided with the OS. You would need to utilize PowerShell for that.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997210(EXCHG.80).aspx

In regards to the cache, which is pointed out in the comment, here is the link to the article which describes it.
Thanks for pointing this out. Very informative:  http://theessentialexchange.com/blogs/michael/archive/2008/01/18/Exchange-Server-Caches.aspx

Comment: Take note that the Exchange dsaccess cache may have some bearing on how well this works for you. It may not "pick up" the disabling or re-enabling of the mailbox right away.